# asp.net session expired and cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm new in stackoverflow.
Our development team is helpless at this moment.
We have two asp.net test sites. Both are showing the message "asp.net session has expired and cannot be found" every time we produce a rdlc report.
It started the last 2 days. Our app had negligible performance issues in the last half-year,  but now even when we copy our production (safe and working thank god so far) version to the test environment-the same massage appears, and the web-site is hanged, terribly slow! And right After that no report is working.
The system team claims that iis is working fine and its our code.
If so, how come the production code not working either on the test server? Not mentioning we havent changed anything in the code.
Major problem: profiling on the test server is prohibited in our organization.
So all we have is "asp.net session end" which also appears in scom (monitor app), and there are no errors appears in global.asax.
And thats It! Nothing more. No other error messages

How can we dig a little deeper finding the cause for this problem?

Anybodies help will be highly appriciated

Comment: Are you able to see anything in the event viewer ??

Comment: Are you seeing this message in your logs.if yes which method/event is writing that for you.